# What's so strange about Ger Chassidim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

"Ger" means "stranger".

I met many Ger Chassidim. I don't find them strange at all. OK, they wear *spodeks* instead of *shtreimlach*. So what? That doesn't make them "strange". I sometimes wear a Washington Senators baseball cap when davening. I think that's strange. (OK, I admit that I do strange things - is that strange?)

So what makes this group of Chassidim strange or stranger than any other Chassid or any other Jew for that matter?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 6):

If only it was just the spodek:

They stuff their pants into the socks.
They tie their payos under the yarmulke... which is shiny and pointed.

But all of this just in the eyes of the beholder. They call themselves "Gur", which means "very" in Yiddish. So "Gur Chassidim" just means "very Chassidic people"...